# Android. Error while build process inside my ViewModelFactory after update androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle libs to 2.5.0 version

Tags: android, viewmodel, factory

After the last update of `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle` to newest  `2.5.0` version I can't build my project. I got this error in my ViewModelFactory

`Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option`

Here is one of the my factory:

```
class BookingViewModelFactory(private val api: ApiClient, private val localStorage: SharedPreferencesRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(BookingViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return BookingViewModel(api, localStorage) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

I even was trying to re-work to a new Factory approach but the error still occurs.

After research didn't find anyone who faced such problem so I guess I made some stupid mistake. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion about this issue on Issue Tracker with Status:

> Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)

And starting with kotlin 1.6.20 this problem will not appear. However if some one faced this problem like me you can fix it by adding this part to your `build.gradle:`

```
android {
   ...
   kotlinOptions {
       ...
       freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-Xjvm-default=all",
        ]
   }
}
```

Here is an actual discussion

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217593040